# Show an element relative to another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dhtml, css-position

I am working on an interface that requires that the user can click on a button, and then I will show a floating div positioned relative to the button (you can kind of think of it as the area that shows when you click the down arrow on a dropdown).

How can I correctly position this floating element adjacent to the button which was clicked (which could be anywhere on the page)?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Choose Something" />

<div id="select">
  ...
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#select { position: absolute; display: none; }
```

and Javascript:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var sel = $("#select");
  var pos = $("#btn").offset();
  if (sel.is(":hidden")) {
    sel.attr({
      top: pos.top + 20,
      left: pos.left
    });
    sel.show();
  } else {
    sel.hide();
  }
});
```

Basically you absolutely position the floating div to remove it from the normal flow and then use [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to figure out where to put it in relation to the button.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the position of the button [by using `.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

For example:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  var o = $(this).offset();
  $("#myDiv").css({'position': 'absolute','left':o.left,'top',o.top});
});
```

This would position it right on top of the button, just adjust that left/top wherever in relation you want it to go.

For example to place it below the button change the top portion to `'top': o.top + $(this).height()` or to right right of the button: `'left':o.left + $(this).width()`

Answer (score 1):

You should both get and set the position using .offset(), in case the element is positioned hierarchically.

For example2

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Choose Something" 
     style="position: absolute; top: 100px;" />
<div style="position: absolute; top: 200px;">parent div
    <div id="myDiv" style="position: absolute; top: 20px;">child div</div>
</div>

$("#myButton").click(function () {
    var o = $(this).offset();
    $("#myDiv").offset({
        'left': o.left,
        'top': o.top - 20
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R5YM6/1/